# How do I get Audio Assets Player to pause?

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I'm learning to use Flutter in FlutterFlow and working on a custom function that plays mp3s from a link. I'm using the Assets Audio Player library.

When I call the function I can get the audio to play but I can't get it to pause when I call it again- I'm using the PlayOrPause action. I suspect it's because I'm not referencing the paying instance- but how do I do that?

Here's my code:

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/supabase/supabase.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';

Future assetsAP() async {
  // Add your function code here!

  var assetsAP = AssetsAudioPlayer.withId("0");

  try {
    await assetsAP.open(
      Audio.network(
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/king-a1558.appspot.com/o/users%2F191vQKCdf8eBy1%2Fuploads%2F1674554237169000.mp3?"),
      autoStart: false,
    );
  } catch (t) {
    //mp3 unreachable
  }
  assetsAP.playOrPause();
}
```